# "Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause."

Tags: word-order, conjunction, ellipsis

Was die Wortreihenfolge des folgenden Satzes betrifft:

> Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause.

Ist die Reihenfolge auch dann korrekt, wenn man daraus schlussfolgern lassen möchte, dass der zweite Satz durch denselben Zeitraum beschränkt ist als der erste (i.e. durch die Zeitangabe "Nach dem Frühstück")? Wäre es nicht zu erwarten, dass der zweite Satz durch eine Art von Elipsis beispielsweise folgendermaßen beeinflusst würde:

> Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und (nach dem Frühstück) bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht, wie man den Satz sonst verstehen sollte denn als "Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren, und in dieser Zeit bleibt meine Mutter zuhause." Schlichtweg, weil jede andere Sinnkonstellation erst einen aufwendig zu erdenkenden Kontext erforderte. - Als altmodisch-konservativer Zeichensetzer vermisse ich übrigens das Komma zwischen den beiden (vollständigen!) Hauptsätzen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Der Satz

> Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause.

ist grammatisch mehrdeutig hinsichtlich der Frage, ob die Zeitangabe *nach dem Frühstück* sich auch auf den zweiten Hauptsatz *meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause* bezieht (Lesart A) oder nicht (Lesart B). Die jeweiligen logischen Strukturen lassen sich durch Klammerung verdeutlichen:

- A: [[Nach dem Frühstück]: [[Ich gehe spazieren] und [meine
  Mutter bleibt zu Hause]]]
- B: [[Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren] und [meine Mutter bleibt
  zu Hause]]

*Pragmatisch* wird Lesart A dadurch stark gemacht, dass die beiden Verben *spazieren gehen* und *zu Hause bleiben* aus dem gleichen semantischen Feld stammen, und in diesem Feld konträr zueinander sind. Die Gricesche Konversationsmaxime der *Relevanz* ("Sage nichts, was nicht zum Thema gehört, wechsle nicht das Thema; Beachte den Gesprächskontext vorangegangener Kommunikation und das Vorwissen deines Kommunikationspartners.") legt nahe, dass dieser Zusammenhang nicht zufällig, sondern thematisch ist: Die Lesart A liegt nahe, da man davon ausgehen kann, dass die beiden Tätigkeiten miteinander verglichen werden sollen (und nicht der Umstand dass ich nach dem Frühstück spazieren gehe mit der kontextfreien Tatsache, dass meine Mutter -- grundsätzlich -- zu Hause bleibt.)

*Syntaktisch* ist allerdings zunächst Lesart B naheliegend, und Lesart A ist aus syntaktischer Sicht begründungsbedürftig. Das zeigt sich etwa am Vergleichssatz

> Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter ist eine freundliche Frau.

*Syntaktisch* ist der Vergleichssatz analog zum Ausgangssatz. Da aber die *pragmatischen* Argumente für Lesart A im Vergleichssatz wegfallen, scheint hier nur noch B richtig zu sein.

Damit A syntaktisch gefordert wäre, würde man wohl

> ?? Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

sagen müssen. Dies scheint mir aber eine ungrammatische oder zumindest sehr unübliche Wortreihenfolge, eine Inversion, zu sein.

Die Ambiguität (Zweideutigkeit) wird auf der grammatischen Ebene zunächst dadurch bedingt, dass [meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause] sowohl als einfaches Präsens oder auch als futurisches Präsens gelesen werden kann.

Diese Ambiguität wird zudem dadurch verstärkt, dass es für beide Lesarten jeweils vereindeutigende Sätze gäbe, die nicht komplizierter wären. Für Lesart B wäre eine Umstellung der beiden Hauptsätze vereindeutigend:

> Meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause und ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren.

Auch die Verwendung eines Adverbs im zweiten Hauptsatz, das die etwaige Bedeutung von *nach dem Frühstück* entwertet, würde vereindeutigend wirken:

> Ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt gern zu Hause.
>
> Ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt immer zu Hause.
>
> Ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt seit Jahren nur noch zu Hause.

Für Lesart A

> Ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren, wohingegen meine Mutter zu Hause bleibt.
>
> Ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren, während meine Mutter zu Hause bleibt.

oder mit der gebräuchlicheren Konjunktion *aber*

> Ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren, aber meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause.

oder auch durch Verwendung des Futurs anstelle des futurischen Präsens:

> Ich werde nach dem Frühstück spazieren gehen, aber meine Mutter wird zu Hause bleiben.

Dass keine dieser paradigmatischen Varianten gewählt wird, lädt die Ambiguität zusätzlich auf. Pragmatisch wird eine Disambiguisierung (Vereindeutigung) durch den Kontext hergestellt werden, wenn Eindeutigkeit notwendig für das Verständnis des Gemeinten ist. Ohne weiteres würde ich wegen der genannten Griceschen Maxime und der semantischen Beziehung der Prädikate der Hauptsätze von Lesart A ausgehen.

Comment: Tut mir leid, aber bereits zu Beginn haben Sie einen Fehler, der Ihre Mehrdeutigkeits-These zunichte macht: Die geklammerten Sätze A und B sind verschieden. In A steht _ich gehe_ und in B steht _gehe ich_.Dass A und B ob dieses Unterschieds auch inhaltlich verschieden gelesen werden können, steht außer Frage, aber es ist nicht der gleiche Ausgangssatz, der durch bloße Klammerung anders gelesen werden kann.

Comment: +1 für die sehr logische Darstellung der weitaus höheren Wahrscheinlichkeit, dass A gemeint ist.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ja, ich habe mich verschrieben. Ich meinte nicht die grammatische Struktur, sondern die logischen Beziehungen. Ich habe das editiert. Danke für den Hinweis.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Die Mehrdeutigkeits-These sehe ich dadurch allerdings nicht zunichte gemacht. Aus syntaktischer Sicht ist ja eher Lesart A begründungsbedürftig, Lesart B ist eigentlich die syntaktisch naheliegendere. Ich habe auch das ergänzt

Comment: "Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter ist eine freundliche Frau. (...) Da aber die pragmatischen Argumente für Lesart A im Vergleichssatz wegfallen, scheint hier nur noch B richtig zu sein." - finde ich nicht. Allein dadurch, dass Beides im selben Satz steht, überwiegt für mich beim Lesen eindeutig die zeitliche Einschränkung vom Satzanfang und drängt unweigerlich Lesart A auf, auch wenn mir die Aussage relativ unsinnig erscheint. Das  ändert sich mE erst durch einen speziellen Kontext, wenn es sich beispielsweise um eine direkte Antwort auf eine Aussage handelt, die ...

Comment: ... ihrerseits zwei voneinander unabhängige Aspekte nennt (z.B.: "Du hängst doch nach dem Frühstück immer nur mit deiner zickigen Mutter zu Hause herum.").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Verstehe ich dich richtig, du würdest das also tatsächlich als "Nach dem Frühstück ist meine Mutter eine freundliche Frau" lesen?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ja, genau das heißt der Satz unweigerlich für mich. Sicher, ich würde mich fragen, wieso das so ist (wobei ich die mögliche Erklärung, dass der Dame ein leerer Magen vielleicht einfach aufs Gemüt schlägt, gar nicht für so abwegig oder außergewöhnlich halte), aber auf die Idee, dass "meine Mutter ist eine freundliche Frau" gar nicht im Zusammenhang mit der zeitlichen Einschränkung gemeint ist, würde ich ohne den oben genannten Kontext eher nicht kommen.

Comment: Ich kann die Logik dieser Antwort nicht nachvollziehen. Ich würde "Meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause und ich gehe nach dem Frühstück spazieren." immer noch als A lesen.

Comment: "... bleibt gern zu Hause" -- denke nicht, dass "gern" ein "nach dem Frühstück" entwertet. *aber* impliziert eine Wertung, während *während* auch *während dessen* sein könnte. Immerhin würde *während dessen bleibt ...* die in der Frage enthaltene und mehrmals empfohlene Syntax beibehalten.

Answer (score 2):

> Wäre es nicht zu erwarten, dass der zweite Satz durch eine Art von Elipsis beispielsweise folgendermaßen beeinflusst würde:
>
> > Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und (nach dem Frühstück) bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

Das ist so nicht richtig, denn die Ellipse würde einen anderen Satz ergeben als gesucht wird. Wenn, dann wäre es *Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt (nach dem Frühstück) zuhause.*

Daran wäre nichts auszusetzen, aber so spricht niemand. Wenn die Zeitangabe für den gesamten Satz gelten soll, könnte das als Ellipse erklärt werden. Das ist jedoch nebensächlich, denn so vollständig für den Ursprung der Elipse erforderlich spricht niemand. (Edit: Vielleicht wird *Ellipse* aber in der Theorie auch weiter gefasst, das will ich nicht ausschließen. Edit2: *während dessen* käme dem auszulassenden Teil vielleicht am nächsten)

Tatsächlich ist es *zu Hause*, das einen Bezug zu *dem Frühstück* impliziert. Vgl. *Montag kommt Jochen nach Berlin und Ich hole Ihn ab.* Da bezieht sich *Ihn* ohne Zweifel auf *Jochen*.

Eine weitere Zeitangabe ist ohnehin nicht nötig, da Sprache grundlegend sequentiel aufgebaut, und chronologische Erzählung der Regelfall ist, wobei Gleichzeitigkeit, die grundlegendste Regel ist. Das ist in diesem Fall gleichbedeutend mit unmittelbarer Abfolge, da der Spaziergang erstmal los gehen muss, um darüber zu sagen, jemand sei nicht mitgekommen.

**Edit** die vorgeschlagene Version *... und bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause* betreffend:

Ich vermute, das Subjekt nach dem "und" verdeutliche die Einführung dessen. Das Verb vorangestellt ließe dagegen unklar, auf wen es sich bezieht. Da der Verbstamm noch vor der Flektion gehört wird, würde die Flektion dabei auch nicht helfen, bzw. würde eine gleichbleibende Flektion gar nicht helfen. Vgl *Danach geht er spazieren und nimmt Daniel einen Film auf*. Das wäre doppeldeutig: *er nimmt etwas für D auf* oder *D nimmt etwas auf*? Vgl auch *... und meine Mutter besuchen*, *... und besuche meine Mutter*.

Answer (score 0):

Die Ausgangsfrage verstehe ich so: Worauf bezieht sich die adverbiale Bestimmung *nach dem Frühstück* jeweils in den folgenden drei Sätzen?

> (A) Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause.
>
> (B) Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und nach dem Frühstück bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.
>
> (C) Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

Außerdem ist zu klären, ob (C) eine Ellipse von (B) ist.

#### Durch *und* verbundene Hauptsätze

> (A) Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause.

Hier handelt es sich um zwei durch *und* verbundene Hauptsätze, nämlich

> 1. Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren.
> 2. Meine Mutter bleibt zu Hause.

Nach der alten Rechtschreibung musste vor *und* ein Komma gesetzt werden; gemäß der [Neuen Deutschen Rechtschreibung](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) (§ 73) ist das Komma optional. Wie auch immer: **Die adverbiale Bestimmung *nach dem Frühstück* bezieht sich nur auf 1.**

Auch bei

> (B) Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und nach dem Frühstück bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

handelt es sich um zwei durch *und* verknüpfte Hauptsätze, nämlich

> 1. Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren.
> 2. Nach dem Frühstück bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

Jeder von ihnen hat eine eigene adverbiale Bestimmung, **die (zufällig) die gleiche ist, nämlich *nach dem Frühstück*.**

#### Durch *und* abgegrenzte Aufzählungspunkte

Nun könnte man meinen, dass

> (C) Nach dem Frühstück gehe ich spazieren und bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

eine Ellipse von (B) wäre. Dem kann aber aus zweierlei Gründen nicht so sein: Nehmen wir erstens an, es wäre tatsächlich eine Ellipse. Dann ließe sich die im zweiten Hauptsatz weggelassene adverbiale Bestimmung aber gar nicht rekonstruieren. Wir allein wüssten zwar, dass es zufällig die gleiche war wie die noch existierende adverbiale Bestimmung im ersten Hauptsatz, aber ohne dieses Wissen wäre niemand zu erraten in der Lage, was sie denn ursprünglich war.

Der zweite Grund ist, dass (C) eine andere Satzstruktur hat. (Bei einer echten Ellipse bleibt die Satzstruktur nach dem Weglassen ja erhalten.) Es ist nämlich eine gewöhnliche Aufzählung. Man könnte das als Liste schreiben:

> (D) Nach dem Frühstück:
>
> - gehe ich spazieren und
> - bleibt meine Mutter zu Hause.

Und weil es eben eine Aufzählung ist, **bezieht sich die adverbiale Bestimmung *nach dem Frühstück* auf beide aufgezählte Handlungen.**

---

<sup>**Edit:** Durch einige Kommentare angeregt, habe ich versucht zu erklären, weshalb beim letzten Beispiel keine Ellipse vorliegt, sondern eine gewöhnliche Aufzählung.</sup>